# Das wichtigste Versorgungsystem ist/sind die elektrischen Netze

Tags: grammatical-number

> Die moderne Gesellschaft ist in hohem Maße von Energie abhängig und das wichtigste Versorgungsystem ist/sind die elektrischen Netze.

Welche Formulierung ist richtig und warum? Ist oder sind?

Comment: Oder: "bilden".

Comment: Nebenbei, es heisst vollkommen richtig "Netz" und nicht "Netzwerk". "Netzwerk" wird meistens als Anglizismus (von "network") angesehen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es heisst entweder

> Das wichtigste Versorgungssystem *ist* das elektrische Netz.

oder

> Das wichtigste Versorgungssystem *sind* die elektrischen Netze.

Das Netz ist hier Nominativobjekt und bestimmt in diesem Fall den Kasus des Verbs (obwohl das Versorgunssystem ja beide Male Einzahl ist). Der Satz kann auch gedreht werden:

> Das elektrische Netz ist das wichtigste Versorgungssystem.
>
> Die elektrischen Netze sind das wichtigste Versorgungssystem.

Ähnliche Formulierungen:

> Sein Einkommen ist das Taxi.

aber:

> Sein Einkommen sind die Taxis.

Ob es dafür eine offizielle Grammatikregel gibt, weiss ich aber nicht, das hier ist aus dem Sprachgefühl hergeleitet.